# Android Studio: how to debug an addon app that has no launcher activity?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, add-on

I want to debug an app which has no launcher of its own because it is a plugin for another app.

How do I debug it?

I tried setting in the IDE launcher configuration under **Launch Options** > **Launch**: *nothing* but then it won't stop on any breakpoints.

Setting **Launch**: *MyActivityName* results in the following error message:

```
Error running MyActivityName: The activity must be exported or contain an intent-filter
```

Given that the app code is only called by the 'host' app it obviously does not require any intent filters or an exported activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just mark your activity in Manifest as

```
android:exported=true
```

and run debug on this activity